# custom Zoom in/out on JPanel is not linear

Tags: java, swing

To avoid wasting your time I will make it short:

**My project**: a graphical presentation of the Mandelbrot set.

**My progress**: finished except a bug in the zoom in/zoom out feature

**The bug**: The zoom in scale is smaller (slower) than the zoom out scale

---

**The shorter version:** how can I simulate a zoom in/out by a factor on a jpanel.

In the end a small section of the jPanel should be enlarged to the whole jPanel.
Every pixel in the jPanel represents an integer number, but you don't have to worry about a lack of integers after the zoom in.

---

**The longer version (only if you need more information):**

the zoom-function in the Mandelbrot set:

```
public void recalculate(int x, int y, int width, int height, double scale){
    downright=new Complex(upleft.getReal()+stepwidth*(x+width/scale),upleft.getImg()-stepwidth*(y+height/scale));
    upleft=new Complex(upleft.getReal()+stepwidth*(x-width/scale), upleft.getImg()-stepwidth*(y-height/scale));
    stepwidth=(downright.getReal()-upleft.getReal())/width;
    calc(lastrep);
}
```

A short terminology:

- downright is the bottom-right complex number, the last pixel to be painted on the jpanel
- upleft is, therefore, the top-left complex-number, the first pixel to be painted on the jpanel
- stepwidth is the distance between each complex number represented by one pixel
- calc is finally the function that calculates every color for each pixel according to the Mandelbrot set rules

the width and height parameters are the pixel width/height of the jpanel, x and y are the coordination where to zoom in and scale the factor for the zoom.

When I call this function `mandelbrot.recalculate(x,y, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10);` than  this should zoom in on the point (x,y) so that the new represented image is 1/5 of the actual image.

1/5 should be because the start of the image (upleft) is 1/10 of the amount of pixels of the full width and height shifted to the up and left of the point (x,y) and the end of the image (downright) is 1/10  of the amount of pixels of the full width and height shifted down and right.

So if I call the function after the zoom in like this: `mandelbrot.recalculate(x,y, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0.1);`
it should reverse the whole process, but it doesn't

---

this is the intended zoom: [image: Zoom in on Mandelbrotset]

Comment: this is already an essay why dont you publish it in a newspaper??

Comment: I added a short explanation as you suggested @gpasch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was rather simple.
The Problem was the attempt to calculate the zoom in as well as the shift to a new midpoint in one go.

Since the shift to the new midpoint is dependent on the zoom in, you can't put that into one equation, or at least only with a lot of effort.

I changed my code like shown below, so that I first calculate the zoom in and then shift the anchor to the wanted position. Sometimes the longer way is the better way.

```
//The new midpoint needs the old stepwith to calculate correctly
Complex newmidpoint = new Complex(upleft.getReal()+x*stepwidth, upleft.getImg()-y*stepwidth);

//zooming in
double distwidth = downright.getReal()-upleft.getReal();
double distheight = upleft.getImg()-downright.getImg();
double newreal = upleft.getReal()+(1/scale)*distwidth;
double newimg = upleft.getImg()-(1/scale)*distheight;
downright=new Complex(newreal, newimg);
stepwidth=(downright.getReal()-upleft.getReal())/width;

//the old midpoint is actually the already zoomed in midpoint, it needs the new stepwidth
Complex oldmidpoint = new Complex(upleft.getReal()+width/2.0*stepwidth,upleft.getImg()-height/2.0*stepwidth);
Complex diffmidpoint = newmidpoint.subtract(oldmidpoint);

upleft=new Complex(upleft.getReal()+diffmidpoint.getReal(),upleft.getImg()+diffmidpoint.getImg());
downright=new Complex(downright.getReal()+diffmidpoint.getReal(), downright.getImg()+diffmidpoint.getImg());
calc(lastrep);
```